# Select Dropdown to not show chosen element

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, wysiwyg

I have created a select that will drop down to reveal the options of the different types of line spacing. However, I want the select to only show the chosen line spacing icon rather than show the line spacing style that I have currently chosen. If you look at the image chosen below, I have "1.0" shown above the chosen icon. I want to change the CSS or HTML to make the "1.0" (the chosen option) disappear. Thank you!

[image: Image of Current Select]

HTML:

```
 <div class = "lineHeight">
                                        <select id="lineHeightSelect" onchange="changeStyle('line-height', this.value)">

                                            <option value="20px">1.0</option>
                                            <option value="35px">1.5</option>
                                            <option value="50px">2.0</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.lineHeight {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url( 'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pixel-perfect-at-24px-volume-1/24/line-height-512.png' );
    background-position: 6px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 15px 15px;
}

.lineHeight #lineHeightSelect {
    padding: 5px 8px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#lineHeightSelect option:checked {
    display: none;
}

#lineHeightSelect select:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function changeStyle( property, value ) {
        if ( window.getSelection().rangeCount ) {
            var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt( 0 ),
                    contents = range.extractContents(),
                    span = document.createElement( 'span' );

            span.style[ property ] = value;
            span.appendChild( contents );
            range.insertNode( span );
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
        }
    }
```

Comment: please add changeStyle('line-height', this.value) function to the question.

Comment: Ok I have just done so!

Answer (score 0):

What I would say is to add the following:

HTML

```
<option value="20px" onclick="twenty-hide() id="twenty">1.0</option>
```

JavaScript

```
function twenty-hide() {
    document.getElementById('twenty').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

This should hopefully fix your problem. First apply it to one, then if it works add the others. If it doesn't (I'm still learning JS) then don't hesitate to tell me that.